# How to reload metadata in teiid

Tags: spring-boot, teiid

I need to reload metadata in spring-boot-teiid. How to i can get it?
Need two methods

1. Reload in application by cron @Sheduled
2. Reload from call endpoint in actuator

And another question, can i get only metadata delta (updated metadata)?

Answer (score 0):

With the current model, the metadata load only happens during the deployment of the VDB, which in Teiid using spring boot is always at the start of the application. You can figure out ways to redeploy the VDB to update the metadata or bootstrap other ways to update metadata of a single source and then update the VDB (redeploy) with that to take the changes into effect.

we have not invested in any utilities to give delta of metadata changes. Teiid does have a lot of visitor pattern implementations, I suppose one could traverse the metadata tree that generates a report like that with some work.